# How do I integrate a custom filter inside a view

Tags: views, 8, files

I am using entity browser to view my uploaded images. And now I want to integrate a new filter to the view. My objective is to filter the images from the URI path. Currently view has a field in Filter Criteria section in the view with a textfield to enter a part of a URI and filter. But I need to  filter the images with a custom dropdown which has only specific values in the URI.

Lets say my URIs looks as below.

```
s3://2019-01/image-set-one/image.jpg
s3://2019-01/image-set-two/image.jpg
```

I need to integrate a dropdown to the filter criteria of the view with elements `image-set-one` and `image-set-two` which will filter the images accordingly. I am using entity browser, so I need to add that field inside the view instead of getting the results and filter after.

This is a screen shot of the view that I am using.

[image]

Below is a preview of my entity browser that I am using with the above view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for above. I can add a field in the filter criteria selecting the URI. And expose that filter to the user with a grouped filter. In the grouped filter I can define my own keys and parameters with an operator. That worked pretty well.